# Send TCP SYN over IPv6 using Python

Tags: python, sockets

I have a Python project which I need to send simple TCP SYN message to an IPv6 address and using raw socket. My script can be executed without error but there was no syn packet sent. I am not sure in my script the IPv6 header, TCP header or IPv6 raw socket which one went wrong. The network was configured for IPv6, so network issues can be excluded.

Here is my script, I am using Python 2.4 on RHEL 5:

```
import socket, sys
from struct import *

# checksum functions needed for calculation checksum
def checksum(msg):
    s = 0
    # loop taking 2 characters at a time
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        w = (ord(msg[i]) << 8) + (ord(msg[i+1]) )
        s = s + w

    s = (s>>16) + (s & 0xffff);
    s = ~s & 0xffff

    return s

def init_tcp_syn_packet_v6(source_port,dest_port, source_ip, dest_ip):
    packet = '';
    # ip header fields
    version     = 6                       #4 bit
    traffic_class = 0                     #8 bit
    flow_level  = 1                       #20 bit
    payload_len = 20 #not true lenght, I just selected a random value        #16 bit
    next_header = socket.IPPROTO_TCP      #8 bit
    hop_limit   = 255                     #8 bit
    saddr = socket.inet_pton ( socket.AF_INET6, source_ip )  #128 bit
    daddr = socket.inet_pton ( socket.AF_INET6, dest_ip   )  #128 bit

    ver_traff_flow = (version << 8) + traffic_class
    ver_traff_flow = (ver_traff_flow << 20) + flow_level

    ip_header = pack( '!IHBB', ver_traff_flow, payload_len, next_header, hop_limit)
    ip_header = ip_header + saddr + daddr

    # tcp header fields
    seq = 0
    ack_seq = 0
    doff = 5    #4 bit field, size of tcp header, 5*4 = 20 bytes
    #tcp flags
    fin = 0
    syn = 1
    rst = 0
    psh = 0
    ack = 0
    urg = 0
    window = socket.htons (5840)    #maximum allowed window size
    check = 0
    urg_ptr = 0

    offset_res = (doff << 4) + 0
    tcp_flags  = fin + (syn << 1) + (rst << 2) + (psh <<3) + (ack << 4) + (urg << 5)

    tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , source_port, dest_port, seq, ack_seq, offset_res, tcp_flags,  window, check, urg_ptr)

    source_address = socket.inet_pton( socket.AF_INET6, source_ip )
    dest_address = socket.inet_pton( socket.AF_INET6, dest_ip )

    placeholder = 0
    protocol = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
    tcp_length = len(tcp_header)
    psh = source_address + dest_address + pack('!BBH' , placeholder , protocol , tcp_length);
    psh = psh + tcp_header;

    tcp_checksum = checksum(psh)
    # make the tcp header again and fill the correct checksum
    tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , source_port, dest_port, seq, ack_seq, offset_res, tcp_flags,  window, tcp_checksum , urg_ptr)

    packet = ip_header + tcp_header

    return packet

#main 
#create raw socket v6
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
#send syn packet
packet = init_tcp_syn_packet_v6( 1235, 80,  '2001:172:22:5::31','2014:2008:0:c::284a:78a4')
```

Comment: Have you tried protocols other than TCP?  I don't know about RHEL, but I seem to recall that Windows doesn't allow TCP packets to be sent with raw sockets for security reasons.  If you're unsure of the header format, I would try to reproduce a "real" packet captured from Wireshark, and confirm the bytes are identical.